# Code Analysis Not Available in This Edition of the Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

I'm trying to run code analysis for the first time on my native C++ application. I'm developing using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and compiling using the Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2013 CTP (CTP_Nov2013), which is the latest (I believe) compiler from MS for C++11. When trying to run Code Analysis I receive the following warning:

> warning D9040: ignoring option '/analyze'; Code Analysis warnings are not available in this edition of the compiler

So I'm wondering if it's because I'm using this new compiler that it's not able to run code analysis or what. But I couldn't find any answers by briefly Googling. The MSDN for Visual Studio says code analysis works for all version of VS except Express. Any help would be appreciated, and if it's a "No it doesn't work with that compiler" then that's fine. Just wondering. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work only for x86 builds.  If you're doing an x64 build,  it won't be available.