# How can I get code analysis to run on unmanaged code in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When trying to run code analysis on Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 (update 4) on unmanaged code, I get the following error:

> Command line warning D9040: ignoring option '/analyze'; Code Analysis warnings are not available in this edition of the compiler

I've seen the similar question at [Code Analysis Not Available in This Edition of the Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354528/code-analysis-not-available-in-this-edition-of-the-compiler), however I'm fairly positive that I'm running the x86 version of the compiler.

Is there any way to know for sure which compiler I'm using, or to force a specific version?

Comment: @hans Good catch, I probably should have that in the main question. I'm running Ultimate.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem as you, did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: @Matt No, I never did find an answer to this. We ended up just ignoring the issue and moving on.